# Count time browser render content

Tags: asp.net, performance, browser, count, render

How can I count time browser render (re-render) my aspx page after page load?

(I have a lot of components on the page,so I need to compare perfomance of different approachs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a browser extension such as [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.

Using the Net panel, you can see a 'timeline' like a Gantt chart of how long each element takes to load, render etc.

[image]